# Show One Level Category id

Tags: categories

This is my cat directory structure

- Games

  - Cricket
    -- Bat
    -- Ball
    -- Wicket
- Machines

  - Electrical
    -- Fan
    -- generator
    -- Computer

I am on category page of Bat or Ball or Wicket. Can anyone tell me how i can get its parent id like id of cricket not Games. I want to get the category id of Cricket.

Comment: Try this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/21065384/5448954 . It may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`get_ancestors()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) will give you an array containing all of the parents of your category with the nearest ancestor being first in the array. So:

```
$cid = 5; // your category ID
$c = get_ancestors($cid,'category');
var_dump($c); // debugging
$p = array_shift($c);
// var_dump($p); // debugging
```

Use `$p` to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$term = get_queried_object();   
$parent= $term->parent;

echo $parent;
```